# Как можно это сохранить чтобы после перезагрузки телефона, или перезапуска программы это

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

Киньте идею пожалуйста.
Есть 3 страницы, в каждой странице список  из 10 строк.
Если нажать на список то он поменяет цвет на красный.

Как можно это сохранить чтобы после перезагрузки телефона, или перезапуска программы это все было ввидно?.

Ответ типо: "Использовать БД" не уместен, так как от этого реализация этих действий мне будет не ясна.
То что можно хранить инфу в БД я знаю, но каким образом это все будет работать?

Comment: @Futurama, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Использовать БД. Этот ответ **уместен**. Если не знаете, как использовать БД, спросите именно это.

Comment: И хватит метить ваши глупые вопросы тегом java-ee. Он не имеет отношения к ее.

Comment: @metalurgus, сори убрал. Я не понимаю просто что я должен хранить в БД.
Допустим 1 = true
0=false
Если я нажал в 1 странице на 5 строку, тоесть её позиция = 4.

То в БД мне написать page=1 pos=4 bool=1. Так чтоли?

Comment: @Futurama А как этот вопрос относится к **среде разработки** android-studio?
По сабжу - что конкретно непонятно? Во время считывания информации из БД задаёшь цвет ... Я даже непонимаю твоей проблемы. Кусок кода чтоли покажи

Comment: Ну вот код выложил и все убежали((((

Comment: Да ща, Бармалей придёт, разрулит всё.

Comment: @argamidon, Это кто? небось не metalugrus случаем?

Answer (score 3):

У тебя всё плохо. Архитектура плохая. Пути решения плохие. Я не могу смотреть на твой код и твои тщетные попытки изобрести очередной велосипед. Я просто покажу как делал я, когда писал свою одну программу для Андроида. Эта схема должна дать примерное понятие о том как **надо** восстанавливаться после поворотов экрана или закрытия. Хочу отметить, что объект preferences заполняется значения совершенно в других местах, а не в call-back методах. Например, у меня есть специальная активити, в которой я выставляю кучу настроек так как размер/цвет форму кисти.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle in) {
        super.onCreate(in);
        if (in != null) {
            // этот блок выполняется когда произошёл поворот Activity.
            // Восстанавливаем из Bundle
        }else {
        // выполняется когда запущено первый раз. считывание из Preferences
        }
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    application.saveStack(undoStack);
    application.saveBitmap(editableBitmap);
    writePaintBrushToBundle(paintBrush, outState);
    writePaintTextToBundle(paintText, outState);
}
public static void writePaintTextToBundle(Paint p, Bundle bundle) {
    bundle.putInt(PAINT_TEXT_COLOR_KEY, p.getColor());
    bundle.putFloat(PAINT_TEXT_SIZE_KEY, p.getTextSize());
}
public static Paint readPaintTextFromBundle(Bundle bundle) {
    Paint p = new Paint();
    int color = bundle.getInt(PAINT_TEXT_COLOR_KEY,
            DEFAULT_PAINT_TEXT_COLOR);
    float textSize = bundle.getFloat(PAINT_TEXT_SIZE_KEY,
            DEFAULT_PAINT_TEXT_SIZE);
    p.setColor(color);
    p.setTextSize(textSize);
    return p;
}
```

Это *примерно* должно прояснить тебе как надо работать с Bundle и Preferences. Если до сих пор непонятно - я могу выложить полный код своей активити. Она большая (писал давно, вместе с антипаттернами), но могу указать на методы на которые стоит обратить внимание.

Comment: @argamidon, если бы это было бы в onCreate беды бы не было, но я это делаю в ListView, который как зараза каждый раз обновляется, удаляет обновляет добавляет удаляет, и ему нужен статический массив где указанно что в этой позиции будет + в это минус и ни как подургому, то что вы написал что по вашему я это в getView должен прописывать? чтобы он по тыщу раз preferences вызывал? чтобы телеофн от такой программы сгорел, У вас Архитектура куда ужасней моей.

Comment: @Futurama Preferences нужно ещё  уметь пользоваться. А не вызывать каждый раз "когда хочу". В своей программе я считываю Preferences **один** раз - инициализирую поля и всё. А когда мне надо, я обращаюсь к **полям**. Неужели ты не можешь в своей программе сделать тоже самое?