# Сохранение содержимого TextView при закрытии приложения

Tags: java, android

Необходимо реализовать сохранение числа из `TextView` при выходе из приложения, а при включении приложения восстановить сохраненное число.

С помощью чего это можно реализовать - `SharedPreferences` или каким то другим способом?

Comment: Если сохранить надо только одно число, то SharesPreference хорошо для этого подойдёт.

Comment: А как реализовать? Есть textview при работе программы оно меняется, надо при выходе сохранить, при последующей загрузке загрузить данные которые были в момент закрытия...

Comment: записать в SQL,File,Bundle...

Comment: Примеры реализации можно? Кусочек кода с SharesPreference будет достаточно...

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/404360/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80/404391#404391

Comment: а лучше http://startandroid.ru/en/ тут поищи. там уроков тьма в том числе по твоей теме

Comment: Лучше посмотреть официальную документацию на эту тему, там все наглядно описанно - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    sPref = getSharedPreferences("data",MODE_PRIVATE);

    loadText();



}

void saveText() {
    Editor ed = sPref.edit();
    ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT, textView.getText().toString());
    ed.commit();

}

void loadText() {
    String savedText = sPref.getString(SAVED_TEXT, null);
    if (savedText == null) {
        System.out.println("первый запуск");
    } else {
        textView.setText(savedText);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sPref = getSharedPreferences("data",MODE_PRIVATE);

void saveText() {
    Editor ed = sPref.edit();
    ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT, textView.getText().toString());
    ed.commit();

}

void loadText() {
    String savedText = sPref.getString(SAVED_TEXT, null);
    if (savedText == null) {
        System.out.println("первый запуск");
    } else {
        textView.setText(savedText);
    }

}
```